# How can I create sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to just a sqlite database but nothing happened.I write a simple code and I havent any error.my app is runninf but I cant see file explorer data>data>com...myexample database folder and my database? how can I fixed?

```
public class sqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 private static final String VERITABANI = "ogrenciler";
    private static final int SURUM = 1;

    public sqliteHelper(Context cont){
        super (cont,VERITABANI,null,SURUM);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE isim(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,isim TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST isim");
        onCreate(db);


    }
```

}

Main :

```
sqliteHelper helper = new sqliteHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

The database is only created when you open it e.g. with `helper.getWritableDatabase()`.